# How to access a PreparedStatement in a multi-thread-environment?

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm using plain-JDBC-Database-Access in a multithreaded environment.

An exception I recently got when working with PreparedStatements (the Oracle flavour) made me aware of the fact, that they are **not** threadsafe.

There is, of course, always the possibility to use ThreadLocal-Variables (or synchronize access to the statement), but is there a more clever way to access a database in a multithreaded way?

Edit: To simplify the problem, I'm accessing the database read-only so parallel transactions are no concern to me.

Comment: what exception you got ? running which code ? can you show some code around thr problem you are having ?

Comment: Basically I got an exhausted resultset because two threads where simultaniously asking for the `next` result in the **same** resultset which had already reached its end. I don't think, the concrete code can be sufficiently compacted to add up to enlightenment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting the `PreparedStatement` into a `ThreadLocal` into will not solve the problem - even the `Connection` must be put into `ThreadLocal`. But then you must make sure, that the connection is also released properly even when exceptions are thrown.

And what about transactions? How do you make sure, that one transaction does not contain stuff from independent threads?

The best way would be to adopt some patterns of EJB containers - here the infrastructure takes care of the resource and transaction management and connection pooling. But retrofitting existing code into EJB or even Spring *correctly* is not an easy task.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I had already searched the line up from the statement and found out that connections are not threadsafe either. I am, however, working with DataSource-objects which are (presumably everywhere but certainly with Oracle) Threadsafe. So my current solution is a ThreadLocal generating PreparedStatements from one DataSource. Transactions are currently no concern to me as all the stuff done by JDBC is readonly (I will clarify this in the Question).

Answer (score 0):

just use the `ThreadLocal` it's the simplest way

you could also delegate all database accesses to a single thread (through a blocking queue) which will also eliminate races. this also allows for easier batching of many statements (though only works for updates, a query requires the pending updates to be flushed first)

Comment: Thanks for Your suggestion to serialize the db-access. However, the whole point of the multithreading environment is to unleash the power of an Oracle cluster which is only really fast if accessed in parallel (think of factor 4.5)